# jQuery not filtering divs as nth-childs?

Tags: jquery

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"><script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('.sss').filter(':nth-child(n+2)').hide();
    $('.sss').on('mouseenter', '.question', function() 
    {   
        $(this).next().slideDown(200).siblings('.answer').slideUp(200);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<div class="sss">
    <div class="question">Question</div>
    <div class="answer">Answer</div>

    <div class="question">Question</div>
    <div class="answer">Answer</div>

    <div class="question">Question</div>
    <div class="answer">Answer</div>

    <div class="question">Question</div>
    <div class="answer">Answer</div>
</div>
```

Divs doesn't have parent-child relation or am I doing a mistake here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.sss').children().filter(':nth-child(n+2)').hide();
```

If you need all `question` div then try:

```
$('.sss').children(':nth-child(2n)').hide();
```

***OR***

```
$('.sss .question').hide();
```

and for all `answer`:

```
$('.sss').children(':nth-child(2n+1)').hide();
```

***OR***

```
$('.sss .answer').hide();
```

Comment: Using children() solved it. Why doesn't jQuery consider some tags like childs and not divs? I saw an example made with ul and li tags, it doesn't require children() to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative not using filter:

```
$('.sss').children(':nth-child(n+2)').hide();
```